# Using a UDF just once to generate Report

Tags: apache-pig

Let say in my Pig Script I just want to generate a summary by calling a UDF just once. 
The UDF will actually take a map and inside it will properly format the map and will return a String.
Is there any way of calling this UDF just once, instead of calling it by

```
report = FOREACH dummyTuple GENERATE myUDF(myMap);
```

One way of doing is to generate a dummyTuple and limiting it to 1 and then calling the above.

Comment: Where will this map come from?

Comment: This map can come from a file or also it can be generated using TOMAP function in PIG

Comment: Please provide more details about the specific thing you are trying to accomplish. There can be multiple ways to do things, so if you try to ask your question in a really general way, it's hard to answer.